# How to get UIAutomation to wait for 2 view changes consistently?

Tags: ios-ui-automation

Xcode 6 beta 6

One workflow in my iOS app has a UINavigationController-controlled VC presenting a modal VC; "Save" in the modal VC dismisses it and pushes a new VC onto the navigation stack:

so from

```
UINC --> VC_1 -modal-> VC_2
```

to

```
UINC --> VC_1 --> VC_3
```

Ideally, I want something like this in my JS:

```
app.navigationBar().buttons()["Save"].tap();
_waitForView(app.navigationBar().withName("VC_3 title"));
...
// assertions re: VC_3 contents
```

where `_waitForView()` throws or otherwise fails the test if the desired view does not appear within the timeout.

On a *few* occasions, it has waited until VC_3 appeared and carried on correctly. More often than not, however, the first VC_3-specific assertion fails on VC_1 contents -- so my `_waitForView()` didn't throw/fail!

I've tried various combinations of `isValid()`, `checkIsValid()`, `pushTimeout()`/`poptimeout()`, and waiting first for VC_1 then VC_3 in `_waitForView()`.

Have others gotten something like this to work consistently?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but this seems to work:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().delay(2);
_waitForView(app.navigationBar().withName("VC_3 title"));
```

I hope not to need the hard-coded 2-second delay long-term, but it'll hopefully be "good enough" while Xcode 6, *et al*, stabilize...